# unable to show table hidden row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application have a table and one tr is display:none. I want to show using jquery.

```js
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var phno = $('#phno').val();
  var mes= $('#message');
  if (phno.length == 10) {

  }else{
    mes.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><label>NAME</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" name="txtname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>EMAIL</label></td>
    <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="txtemail"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>PHONE NO.</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phno" maxlength="10" name="txtphno"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="message" style="display: none; color: red;">
    <td>Invalid Phone Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">REFER</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</form>
```

this is my table. I want to show message row for 5 seconds.I am unable to do that.

this is my jquery. But it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: `('#name')` isn't valid jquery statement. You should write `$` before selector. Use `$('#name')`

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a collection, not a single element. Use getElementById, or stick with jQuery...

Comment: see my edited code.It show for 1sec and then it reset all field.But I want field also filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$("#name")` to get an element istead of `("#name")` and `querySelectorAll` will retrieve a list of elements matching with input. Instead of this use `$("#message")` to get element.

Use below code:

```js
$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phno = $('#phno').val();
    var mes= $('#message');
    if (phno.length == 10) {

    }else{
        $('#message').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><label>NAME</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" style="text-transform:uppercase" name="txtname"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>EMAIL</label></td>
        <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="txtemail"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>PHONE NO.</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phno" maxlength="10" name="txtphno"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="message" style="display: none; color: red;">
        <td>Invalid Phone Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">REFER</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input class="btn" value="click me" type="button"/>
```

Comment: yes...Thanks It show now but it appear only for 1sec. I want to show it for long time.and text disappear from input